# useReduxContext.js:24 Uncaught Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { getDefaultMiddleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import logger from "redux-logger";

const initialState = {
  user: {},
};

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUser(state, action) {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: userSlice.reducer,
  middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware(), logger],
});

export const { setUser } = userSlice.actions;

export default store;
```

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import store, { setUser } from "./store/index";
import { userFetch } from "./ApiHandler/apiHandler"; // Import your action creator
import axios from "axios";

const Root = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  let token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");

  const headers = {
    Authorization: `${token}`,
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const userFetch = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/signin/getuser`,
          { headers }
        );
        dispatch(setUser(response.data.user));
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      }
    };
    if (token) {
      userFetch();
    }
  }, [token]);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store={store} >
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<Root />);
```

Redux Toolkit Configuration:

I imported the necessary functions from `@reduxjs/toolkit`: `createSlice`, `configureStore`, and `getDefaultMiddleware`.

- Created a `userSlice` using `createSlice` with a `setUser` reducer to update the `user` state.
- Exported the `setUser` action from userSlice.actions.
- Configured the Redux store using `configureStore` with the `userSlice.reducer` as the root reducer and added `getDefaultMiddleware()` as the middleware.

Root Component:

- Imported `Provider` and `useDispatch` from `react-redux`.
- Created a `Root` component that will serve as the entry point of the application.
- Within the `Root` component, used the `useEffect` hook to fetch the user data when the component mounts.
- Defined the `userFetch` function inside the `useEffect` hook to make an HTTP request to retrieve the user data using the token from the local storage.
- Dispatched the `setUser` action with the received user data.
- Wrapped the `App` component with the `Provider` component and passed the Redux store as a prop.
- Wrapped the `Root` component with the `BrowserRouter` component to enable routing.

Rendering:

- Used `ReactDOM.render` instead of `ReactDOM.createRoot` to render the application.
- Wrapped the `Root` component with the `Provider` component and passed the Redux store as a prop.
- Rendered the `Root` component inside the root element with the ID of "root" in the HTML file.

I am trying to update global state with `redux-toolkit` but that error is not resolved. I am using `dispatch` redux hook to save data coming from api.

Answer (score 0):

`Root` is the component rendering the React-Redux `Provider` component that provides the Redux context that components need in order to use the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks and anything else Redux related. This means that `Root` itself ***can't possibly*** use the `useDispatch` hook it's trying to use.

Either push this `Root` component logic down lower in the ReactTree, e.g. into `App`, or abstract it into a separate child component.

Example:

```
const CheckToken = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");

    const userFetch = async () => {
      const headers = {
        Authorization: `${token}`,
      };

      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/signin/getuser`,
          { headers }
        );
        dispatch(setUser(response.data.user));
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      }
    };

    if (token) {
      userFetch();
    }
  }, [token]);

  return null;
};

const Root = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <CheckToken />
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<Root />);
```

Since this is really more just code to issue a side-effect it might just be better to abstract it into a custom hook and call it lower in the ReactTree, again e.g. `App`.

```js
export const useCheckToken = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");

    const userFetch = async () => {
      const headers = {
        Authorization: `${token}`,
      };

      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/signin/getuser`,
          { headers }
        );
        dispatch(setUser(response.data.user));
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      }
    };

    if (token) {
      userFetch();
    }
  }, []);
};
```

```
import { useCheckToken } from '../path/to/useCheckToken';

const App = () => {
  useCheckToken();

  ...
};
```

```
const Root = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<Root />);
```

Since you are already using `redux-toolkit` it may also be advantageous to create a think to handle the asynchronous logic.

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export setUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "user/setUser",
  async () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");

    const headers = {
      Authorization: `${token}`,
    };

    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/signin/getuser",
        { headers }
      );
      return response.data.user;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  },
);

const initialState = {
  user: {},
};

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(setUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.user = action.payload;
      });
  },
});
```

```js
export const useCheckToken = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setUser());
  }, []);
};
```

```
import { useCheckToken } from '../path/to/useCheckToken';

const App = () => {
  useCheckToken();

  ...
};
```